# What does "B A V" and "E.S." stand for in French concerning cars, specifically a 2005 VW T5?

Tags: vw

A french garage billed for

- "Diagnostic et Recherce Panne ?"
- "Echange transmission et embout de
  la B A V (extraction) essai"

and replacement parts

- "Transmission E.S."
- "Embout BAV"

I can decipher everything except for BAV and E.S.. What do they mean?
The car is a VW T5.